# Is it possible to get a total_count on a find from Mongo while using limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Im trying to use pagination with Mongo. My issue is if I limit my find results, my count is equal to the .limit value.
Is there some sort of meta value total_count in mongo/mongoose?

UPDATE:
I was able to use mongoose-paginate from npm to accomplish this.

Comment: Not possible. You have to use aggregation.

Comment: The best solution is you have to run separate query to get get count.

Answer (score 0):

```
    objectModel.count({}, function( err, count){
    console.log( "Number of objects:", count );
})
```

i think this is what you need, mongoose has a count query you can use. you can even filter if you want just like in a normal query.

for more information :
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count